# setting the network algorithm in cplex but the solution was obtained with dual simplex

Tags: mathematical-optimization, cplex, network-flow

I am solving a pure network flows problem (min. cost flow model) in python/java using cplex. Hence, I am explicitly telling cplex to use the network algorithm (i.e., `lpmethod = network = 3`). However, after the model is solved, I ask cplex to tell me what algorithm it used to produce the solution, and it tells me it was dual simplex (i.e., i.e., `lpmethod = dual = 2`). I know that when I invoke the network algorithm, cplex extracts an an embedded network to use the network optimizer, and then it uses the solution to construct a starting basis for the full LP problem to be solved with a simplex optimizer. However, I am providing a pure network flow model, so no extraction is needed and definitively no reconstruction to an lp basis is needed after the finding the network solution.

Cplex tells me that I can overcome this step only using the C callable library. However, I am using the .NET, the python, and the Java libraries.

How can I avoid the extra time of extracting the network and rebuilding a basis after obtaining the real solution if I am providing a pure network model and I want to use the Java library?

I am using a massive network with millions of variables, but tried something at a smaller scale. For instance, I am using the cplex python example `lpex3.py`:

```
import cplex
c = cplex.Cplex()
c.parameters.simplex.display.set(2)
c.parameters.read.datacheck.set(1)
c.linear_constraints.add(senses="EEEEEEE",
                            rhs=[-1.0, 4.0, 1.0, 1.0, -2.0, -2.0, -1.0])
flow = [[[1, 6], [1.0, -1.0]],
        [[2, 6], [1.0, -1.0]],
        [[3, 6], [1.0, -1.0]],
        [[2, 5], [1.0, -1.0]],
        [[3, 5], [1.0, -1.0]],
        [[1, 4], [1.0, -1.0]],
        [[2, 4], [1.0, -1.0]],
        [[0, 1], [-1.0, 1.0]],
        [[0, 2], [-1.0, 1.0]],
        [[0, 3], [1.0, -1.0]],
        [[4, 5], [-1.0, 1.0]],
        [[4, 6], [1.0, -1.0]]]

# lower bounds are set to their default value of 0.0
c.variables.add(obj=[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
                        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 2.0],
                ub=[50.0] * 12, columns=flow)
c.parameters.lpmethod.set(c.parameters.lpmethod.values.network) # Here I set the algorithm to network
c.solve()
print("After network optimization, objective is ", c.solution.get_objective_value())
print("Algorithm used: ", c.solution.get_method()) # Here I ask for the algorithm used to produce the solution.
```

However, the output is

```
CPXPARAM_Simplex_Display                         2
CPXPARAM_Read_DataCheck                          1
CPXPARAM_LPMethod                                3
Tried aggregator 1 time.
No LP presolve or aggregator reductions.
Presolve time = 0.00 sec. (0.01 ticks)
Extracted network with 7 nodes and 12 arcs.
Extraction time = 0.00 sec. (0.00 ticks)

Iteration log . . .
Iteration:     0   Infeasibility     =            11.000000 (11)

Network - Optimal:  Objective =    5.0000000000e+00
Network time = 0.00 sec. (0.00 ticks)  Iterations = 6 (5)
After network optimization, objective is  5.0
Algorithm used:  2
```

Clearly, although the problem is a pure network flow model, and I invoke the network algorithm, and no postprocessing is needed, the algorithm used is dual simplex (value of 2). In a small example, this might not be substantial, but when solving multiple network models with millions of variables in parallel within a Column Generation, every second counts.

Comment: If you ask on https://or.stackexchange.com/ you can get answer quicker.

Comment: It may be better to use a plain network code without all the network extraction that Cplex is doing (that has some real overhead). OR-Tools has a fast network code.